# Modelling or modeling?

Tags: orthography

When I want to talk about creating a structural model of a building or bridge, should I say modelling the structure or modeling the structure?

Answer (score 6):

Both are correct and acceptable. *Modeling* is commonly used in the U.S. while *modelling* is used in the UK and many other places.

The last consonant often gets doubled in present participle and past participle when it's a part of a stressed syllable.

For example, the *t* in 'submit' is a part of a stressed syllable so it's doubled in present participle (*submi**tt**ing*) and past participle (*submi**tt**ed*).

The last *t* in 'target' is a part of unstressed syllable so it doesn't get doubled in present participle (targeting) and past participle (targeted).

However, the final ***-l-*** in *unstressed* syllables gets doubled in present participle and past participle in British English and many other dialects.

**British English:**

- trave**l** → trave**ll**ing, trave**ll**ed
- labe**l** → labe**ll**ing, labe**ll*ed
- cance**l** → cance**ll**ing, cance**ll**ed
- mode**l** → mode**ll**ing, mode**ll**ed etc.

**American English:**

- trave**l** → trave**l**ing, trave**l**ed
- labe**l** → labe**l**ing, labe**l**ed
- cance**l** → cance**l**ing, cance**l**ed
- mode**l** → mode**l**ing, mode**l**ed etc.

(You might also want to read the [Wikipedia article on doubling of consonants](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#Doubled_consonants).)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which English dialect you are referring to:

[Modeling vs. modelling:](https://grammarist.com/spelling/model/)

> In American English, the verb model becomes modeled and modeling. Outside North America, the preferred participles are modelled and modelling, with two l‘s. Canadians prefer the double-l forms, though the single-l forms appear about a third of the time. (In contrast, the double-l forms are almost nonexistent in 21st-century American writing, and the single-l forms are similarly rare outside North America.) These spelling preferences extend to modeler (U.S.) and modeller (outside the U.S.).

(The Grammarist)